# How to Count Time Complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

My goal is to make sure the time complexity of the for loop operation is no greater than the length of both strings. So in this example O(m-n) can not be greater than O(28) if I counted right. I'm pretty sure this is exactly the same as the length, but I am not so familiar with Time Complexity.

So my question is, what is the time complexity for the for loops?

So I realized that the time complexity is m*n, which is going to be greater than the length of both strings. I know its frowned upon, but does anyone have any idea how to further reduce it ?

To be clear, the program is checking the String str to see if it contains any of the characters in String set. If it does match, the program is supposed to print the index of the first match than exit. That's just another if statement I was going to add later.

**Code:**

```
String str = "ThisIsTesTingComplexity";
String set = "t9123";

for(int j = 0;j<str.length();j++)
    for(int i = 0;i<set.length();i++)
        if(str.charAt(j)==set.charAt(i))
            System.out.print(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are clearly having a `O(n*m)` time complexity. Just count the number of iterations of your loops : for each iteration of the first loop, the second loop performs m iterations, and there a n iterations of the first loop. CQFD.

Comment: Yes, I realized after further looking. Now I have no clue how else to reduce time complexity. I need to get rid of the quadratic some how.....

Comment: The program is checking the String str to see if it contains any of the characters in String set. If it does match, the program is supposed to print the index of the first match than exit. That's just another if statement I was going to add later.

Comment: And is there a particular reason why you don't use a real `Set` instead of a String ? At the very least, you can use a sorted `char[]` it will still be better

Comment: I am required to use two strings. Isn't it impossible to optimize more? Assuming the worst case scenario you have to check every letter in the String str and the String set.

Comment: Sort your `set` String and perform binary search by hand, as you cannot use `Arrays.binarySearch`. You will have an `(n + m) log(m)` complexity